# Disable the mousewheel scroll/ or any scroll Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am with a situation where i want to disable the scroll, while datais loading via Ajax.

I have tried :-

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo get_site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'my_cat_page',
        bar: bids,
        price: pids,
        catid: ids,
        status: both,
        area: zids,
        cuis: cids,
        noc: noc
    },
    beforeSend: function () {

        jQuery('#TB_overlay').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery(window).scroll().disable();
    },    
    complete: function () {

        jQuery('#TB_overlay').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery("#right_search").html(html);

    },
    success: function (html) {

        jQuery("#right_search").html(html);
        jQuery(window).scroll().enable();
    },   
    failure: function (html) {
        jQuery("#right_search").html("Ajax Failure! Please try again.");
    }    
});
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    });
});
```

Do comment out all the `jQuery(window).scroll().disable() & enable();` code.

Comment: This is simple and works in all situation i think, nice! But could be more specific depending of which ajax request is made